# How is the fastest way to check each digit of a byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte

Given an arbitrary byteArray I need to check if a digit is greater than 9, if so the method returns false. I came to this solution, but I think it's a better way of doind that (maybe with some unary operations or other tricks):

```
for (int i : byteArray)
    if (i/16 > 0x09 || i%16 > 0x09) return false;
```

I tried to convert the number to a string, but it was slower.

Comment: why converting byte back to int? why not compare it directly?

Comment: You can replace `if (i/16 > 0x09 || i%16 > 0x09) return false;` with `return i%16 <= 0x09;`

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example.

Comment: Have you tested your current code? What does it say for the byte 0xFF?

Comment: Related and necessary: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: @office.aizaz you was right about that, IDK why I converted back to int

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash That won’t give the desired result since it’s in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02};
for (byte b : arr) {
      if (b > 0x09) {
          return false;
      }
}
```

As mentioned in comment, OP is interested in comparing each 'nibble':

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02};
for (byte b : arr) {
      if ((b & 0xF0) > 0x90 || (b & 0x0F) > 0x09) {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: The OP wants to check each 4 bit "nybble" of the byte.

Comment: `(b & 0xF0) > 0x09` -> `(b & 0xF0) > 0x90`

Comment: @OleV.V. The maximum byte value is 0x7F, so it can never exceed 0x9F.